# Yii getting Error 403 even if logged in as an admin

Tags: php, yii

```
public function actionCheckout()
{
     echo "Hello World!";
}
```

I just created this very simple code in the controller but when I try to browse it in my URL it shows me this error:

[image]

Even if i'm currently logged in as an Admin but still why can't i access that very simple code.

I will post the accessRules that the CRUD generated, I don't know if this are related to each other but when I try to delete this line, I can already access that page.

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

If you can see there's no checkout being declared on that code so it won't matter.

What do you think are/is the reason for that? Your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks! :)

Comment: The last rule denies all requests that aren't listed in the access rules above it, as you haven't declared `checkout`, it'll be denied no matter who is trying to access it, as the answers below suggest, you need to add the `checkout` action to your access rules

Comment: I don't know why someone would down vote this question because this question is helpful to newbies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access rules in your controller, then you need to add this "checkout" action to those rules.

You need to add 'checkout' to whichever level of access you require in your accessRules() function.  If it is to be accessible to everyone, you'll need:

```
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view', 'checkout'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        )
```

Or for admin only access:

```
        array('allow',  // allow admin user access
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete','checkout'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to 'Checkout' pointing in accessRules, in one place (I set in all allowed action

```
public function accessRules()
{
    array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index', 'view' and 'checkout' actions
        'actions'=>array('index','view', 'checkout'),
        'users'=>array('*'),
    ),
    array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create', 'update' and 'checkout'actions
        'actions'=>array('create','update','checkout'),
        'users'=>array('@'),
    ),
    array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin','delete' and 'checkout' actions
        'actions'=>array('admin','delete','checkout'),
        'users'=>array('admin'),
    ),
    array('deny',  // deny all users
        'users'=>array('*'),
    ),
 }
```